# Is it possible to add/remove a gRPC Service Reference via dotNet CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2019, grpc, dotnet-cli

To create a gRPC service contract client I currently go into Visual Studio and click Add-ServiceReference then follow the steps to point to may protofile and finally generate the client service contract class that I can new up in a client application to interact with the underlying gRPC service.
While that all works, it means that for the 100's of API's that I will be creating, I will need to follow the above steps for each API service contract.

Is there a command line utility that I can invoke to add this proto file service definition file to a target class library?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using the dotnet-grpc cli

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/dotnet-grpc?view=aspnetcore-3.1